# Integrating PL/JSON with Oracle APEX 4.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-06550

I am trying to use PL/JSON in my Oracle APEX application but get the following errors when I attempt to run a Hello, world [example](http://embosa.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/oracle-and-json-using-pljson/) (which works fine when I run the example from SQL*PLUS as sys):

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 20:
PLS-00905: object MY_SCHEMA.JSON is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 20:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_EXT.GET_VARCHAR2' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The version of Oracle database that I am using is 10g XE.

I am guessing that I haven't granted execute privileges correctly on the packages: JSON_EXT, JSON_PRINTER, and JSON_PARSER. I have tried granting execute privileges on the 3 packages to public and APEX_PUBLIC_USER but to no avail. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. I have Google searched for several hours and have yet to come across a post/page that answers my problem or helps explain what is wrong and how I can go about resolving my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't grant execute to PUBLIC or APEX_PUBLIC_USER.

Comment: Are you testing in SQL*Plus with the same schema that is associated with your Apex workspace?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a DESC JSON_EXT, there isn't a GET_VARCHAR2 function (at least in version 0.9.2). There is a GET_STRING function that returns a VARCHAR2.

The page you link to uses PL/JSON version 0.8.6, and it looks like they've done some biggish changes in 0.9

```
  Version: 0.9.0
WARNING: You cannot do an easy upgrade because of changes in the API
    Rewrote the API to increase speed and simplicity
```

Try out the examples in the latest version of the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, that did not help. PL/JSON works outside of Oracle APEX. By changing GET_VARCHAR2 to GET_STRING, I get the following, similar, error message for GET_STRING when I run the code from the SQL Commands page in Oracle APEX: <pre><code> PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_EXT.GET_STRING' must be declared ORA-06550: line 7, column 5: PL/SQL: Statement ignored </code></pre>